# Sort JSON Array in PHP

Tags: php, sorting

How do I sort the "name" field in ASC and also sort in DESC ordering using only php?

Here is what I have thus far

```
$stud = json_encode($arr);
print_r($stud);
```

Which outputs..

```
[{"id":1, "name":"Some Name"},
 {"id":4, "name":"Another Name"},
 {"id":9, "name":"Third Name"}]
```

But this is what I need

```
[{"id":4, "name":"Another Name"},
 {"id":1, "name":"Some Name"},
 {"id":9, "name":"Third Name"}];
```

How would I sort the name column alphabetically after `json_encode()`?

Comment: I suggest you sort it before encoding it.

Answer (score 5):

You decode the JSON string back into PHP. Sort it using the normal PHP sort routines (looks like [uksort](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.uksort.php) is the right one here). Then reencode it.

Serializing data to JSON is something you do in order to transport the data, not to perform operations on it.